# Base64: Basic vs. Mime decoder

Tags: java, base64

I'm on jdk 1.8.

I've to decode a lot of base64 data. Some of the data includes '\r' followed immediately by a linefeed '\n'.

I know the `Base64.getMimeDecoder()` handles this line feeds correctly. But can this really be used as a substitute of `Base64.getDecoder()`. If not, what's the prefert way to decide, what decoder to use? I just have an array of bytes.

Comment: MIME decoder is the only correct decoder if your input contains line feeds. Both other options will not accept input with any characters outside of the base64 alphabet. [The docs of `Base64`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Base64.html) have a concise summary at the top about the differences (that's a Java 17 link, but that class is mostly unchanged since Java 8).

Comment: You must examine the symbol table to determine *which* base64 to use; because the different Base64 decoders use slightly different 64 character symbol tables. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Variants_summary_table) for more.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Isn't it enough to check the data for line feed? If not, what is the easiest way to examin the symbol table?

Comment: @ThiloSchwarz By examining your inputs. It's going to be one of RFC 1421, RFC 2045, RFC 2152, RFC 3501, RFC 4648 §4, RFC 4648 §5, RFC 4880 or the always helpful "Other variations".